# Redirecting all requests of one docker container to another ??

Tags: docker, http-proxy

I have two docker containers running on a host, say A and B. Docker A requests for a service running on some other host and this request and reply is working perfectly. What I want to do is, I want to redirect all requests originating from A to go to the service through container B (used for some auditing) and all the replies coming from the service to reach A through B again.

How can I do this? Is it possible to achieve a transparent setup like this such that A never gets to know that B is auditing its requests and the replies coming for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an entry in `/etc/hosts` of docker container **A** using `--add-host` parameter of `docker run command`. The code on docker container A only need to now the name of this entry. All you need to do is pass this name in `--add-host` parameter point to your docker container **B** if you need auditing service, otherwise you can pass *some other host IP*  directly.

I hope this help.

Comment: If I do this, it no longer remains transparent to A. I guess what you are saying is that I should call container B from A explicitly, where as what I want is that A should make a CALL-C and B should become the man in the middle somehow to intercept that call and A should never know that B also exists somewhere between A and C intercepting the call. When C replies to A's request, it should also go through B in the same way.

Comment: Correct me if i misunderstood you. What you are saying, is it not similar to tha docker ambassador linking?
https://docs.docker.com/articles/ambassador_pattern_linking/

The reason I can not adopt this solution is because in future I may have more containers like 

A1, A2, A3 making requests to C1, C2, C3 and I want all these requests to go through a single B which just grabs these requests, does the processing and forwards them to C1/C2/C3 and does the same thing to the reply coming from them. I cannot make hard coded links b/w B and C1,C2,C3 so that I can support more services dynamically.

Comment: I am looking for the same situation here. 
In kubernetes you can use Hosts aliases... this adds the `<IP address> hostname` to your docker image ( /etc/hosts ) file. 
This works but the requests headers are stripped and the Host says "<IP address>" and not "hostname" ..
Maybe this will help you get to the next step